# php implode question

Tags: php

So I am doing a search and I am using an implode in my select statement, which I find quite useful. Basically this search engine will have 3 different selects which will select different things based on different criteria and when I use my implode I get an error of invalid arguments passed.

Here is my sql statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT camp.title, camp.startDay, camp.typeOfCamp, camp.endDay,
camp.link FROM ((camp INNER JOIN gender ON camp.id = gender.camp_id) 
INNER JOIN grades ON camp.id = grades.camp_id) 
INNER JOIN interests ON camp.id = interests.camp_id 
WHERE ((grades.year = '".implode('\' OR grades.year = \'',$age)."') 
AND gender.gender = '".$gender."') 
OR ((interests.activity = '".implode('\' OR interests.activity = \'',$array)."')
AND (grades.year = '".$age."' AND gender.gender = '".$gender."'))";
```

The second implode for the interests is where I began having my problem and $array is an array. Another thing I don't understand is that when I run my code I get the correct results, but I am still getting the error that I am passing invalid arguments.

Comment: So I must be absolutely retarded because when I went to look for code to post I realized that I just messed up big time and didn't realize that my code was out of order which is where my problem was. Sorry for making this thread for such as simple answer. Thanks guys that did help though it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You may believe what PHP says, normally. If it says it isn't an array you probably didn't pass an array.

And a small tip to save you some code: There is an `IN()` statement in MySQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT camp.title, camp.startDay, camp.typeOfCamp, camp.endDay,
camp.link FROM ((camp INNER JOIN gender ON camp.id = gender.camp_id) 
INNER JOIN grades ON camp.id = grades.camp_id) 
INNER JOIN interests ON camp.id = interests.camp_id 
WHERE (grades.year IN(".implode(',', $age).") 
AND gender.gender = '".$gender."') 
OR (interests.activity IN('".implode("','", $array)."')
AND grades.year = ".$age." AND gender.gender = '".$gender."')";
```

To save the duplicate `gender.gender = $gender` and (maybe) optimize the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT camp.title, camp.startDay, camp.typeOfCamp, camp.endDay,
camp.link FROM ((camp INNER JOIN gender ON camp.id = gender.camp_id) 
INNER JOIN grades ON camp.id = grades.camp_id) 
INNER JOIN interests ON camp.id = interests.camp_id 
WHERE gender.gender = '".$gender."'
AND (
    grades.year IN(".implode(',', $age).") 
    OR (
        interests.activity IN('".implode("','", $array)."')
        AND grades.year = ".$age."
    )
)";
```

Furthermore I think MySQL doesn't require to use all those parentheses for joins:

```
$sql =
"SELECT DISTINCT camp.title, camp.startDay, camp.typeOfCamp, camp.endDay,
camp.link
FROM camp
INNER JOIN gender    ON camp.id = gender.camp_id
INNER JOIN grades    ON camp.id = grades.camp_id
INNER JOIN interests ON camp.id = interests.camp_id 
WHERE gender.gender = '".$gender."'
AND (
    grades.year IN(".implode(',', $age).") 
    OR (
        interests.activity IN('".implode("','", $array)."')
        AND grades.year = ".$age."
    )
)";
```

Now the query should be way better to understand.

Comment: Your right MySQL doesn't require the parentheses, but I had developed this for using an Access DB, but am now trying to get it to work with MySQL. Also this solution did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do everything in on big statement. Why not build your imploded array-strings before you include them in the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Chris, your problem is that you're **not** passing an **array** to the second parameter of implode().

If you see **www.php.net/implode** the second parameter must be of type **ARRAY** so that PHP can start joining your array together with your **delimiter** specified in the first parameter.

A good way to check the data type of your variable is to use var_dump() which will tell you  if something is an array, or int..etc

There are two variables you're passing to **implode()** there. **$age** and **$array**, I am guessing that it's age and you need to modify your code a bit.

Pasting your whole code that's generating $array and $age would help us further to see where you're going wrong in creating those variables.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using strings:

```
OR (interests.activity IN ('".implode("','", $array)."')
```

will neaten up that line.

But I am worried about $age. You use it as if it is an array in:

```
WHERE ((grades.year = '".implode('\' OR grades.year = \'',$age)."')
```

but as a string variable:

```
AND (grades.year = '".$age."' AND gender.gender = '".$gender."'))";
```

I think you should be using the "IN" and implode() expressions for both places you're using $age if it is an array.